# How can I get a field to print at the top of every page in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 3.7.6 to create this report.

I have a report based off of an XML file. There is a 2-column master report and it has a detail band with a subreport.

I have a field called "Name" in the subreport. I want it to print at the top of every page. Or even at the top of every column. I have tried virtually everything I know how to do.

"Print When Detail Overflows" doesn't work, because this setting is **in** the detail.

I sure hope I don't need to create a subreport for every report break I want. I'll have like 4 or 5 subreports.

Is there some way to determine when the page has changed, and then use that event in a "Print When" expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution, presuming the value does not change between pages:

1. Write a query for a subreport that obtains only the *Name* value.
2. Change the dimensions of the subreport to be as small as necessary.
3. Place the subreport in the page header band of the master report.

To answer your question accurately, more details (such as pictures of what you have versus what you want) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pageCount variable which is implicitly available in jasper reports to know whether the page has changed or not.